# Creating partition tables automatically at installation (with or without d-installer)

Tags: partitioning, encryption

This is for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, desktop.

With d-installer, you can create recipes and build different partition tables quickly.

I'm trying to build multiple mount locations automatically, but the challenge seems to be that the d-installer solution I use is unreliable. For some hardware, it works. Other hardware it fails. Now there may be a subtle difference between hardware drives, but I'd like a more reliable option.

Do you know of a way to better automate building partition tables, or is there a known preseed that works (that I can't find because I've tried so many from wiki)?

The partition tables should also be lvm and support encryption.